How do I fill/fix this small gap between a wall and a wardrobe frame?
I am trying to make a IKEA PAX wardrobe look built in. I built an MDF frame around it, put some frog tape down and primed and painted.
When I took the tape off, I didn't get the smooth finish that I was after and even with the doors on the wardrobe (which I was hoping would hide the rubbish finish of cracked lines gaps and dark patches), you can see the poor finish.
In some places the frame comes slightly beyond the wardrobe frame.

What can I do to fix the appearance of this gap to give it a better finish?

@keshlam - currently the gap between my fake wall and the frame is obvious (even with the doors on)...just trying to make it less obvious with as minimal effort as I can get away with.

What about some small white trim boards attached to the MDF along the gap?

@negacao - can you give me an example of the sort of thing you mean so I can visualise?

Some acrylic caulk?

Something like quarter round joint moulding, or regular trim boards. I have to admit I like @RMDMan's answer below better, though.

@Cheetah: please edit that into the question. "Finish is rubbish" tells us nothing about what your concerns are, and comments may go away over time.

@keshlam - apologies I thought it was obvious from the picture...edited, thanks

Ah. To me, "finish" means surface treatment, and the surface gets levelled before finish is applied via planing, sanding, putty, or other means.

You have to bevel that edge first. You drag the corner of a scraper down it, until it's a true recess, then you caulk it. If it flies out more than an 1/8", you have to do a lot of scraping, some setting-type mud, and then caulk. - There is no 'finishing' that until you fix the wall. Unless you want casing (door trim) around it, but that's so 90s.

What is visible are the gaps between the wardrobe and the MDF.  They show as darker so the eye sees them.
Apply latex caulk to the gaps. Force it in the cracks and gaps with your finger. Then wipe it with a damp sponge.  Allow to dry for at least 6 hours, prefered overnight.
When the caulk is dry, tape the edge of the wardrobe frame with your frog tape. Leave a 1/8 inch edge of the wardrobe exposed for paint.
Then when you paint the MDF and new caulk it blends into the edge of the wardrobe.  With everything the same color and no dark cracks and gaps the unit looks built in...or as close as you will get without actually having it built in.

Ok so I've put a very thin layer of caulk down...presumably I should prime before painting - correct? (after its cured)

Paintable caulk does not need to be primed.  Priming depends on what caulk you used.

it's this: https://www.screwfix.com/p/no-nonsense-decorators-caulk-white-310ml/57568 ...says it's paintable...is it still better to prime to avoid cracking in your opinion?

Priming will not avoid cracking. The amount is so small it is not likely to crack. It is paintable as is. Priming is by your choice.

This gave me a satisfactory result, thanks

Your are welcome.  Glad things worked for you.
